# Align UIImageView to bottom of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autoresizingmask

I want to align red image at bottom of scrollview. In portrait orientation it looks fine as the height of scrollview is equal to view height.

[image: Potrait orientation]

But in landscape mode it looks like this, when in landscape I want it to be completely hidden until the user scroll till the bottom of scrollview, so that the red image is always at the bottom of scroll view. Currently it looks like this in landscape mode.

[image: Landscape orientation]

I have added red image as a subview of scrollview and applied bottommarginautoresizingmask to it.

Comment: set the auto layout/ autoresize.

Comment: I am already using autoreszingmask bottom margin

Comment: not only bottom margin, it needed flexible width, height ,left and right masks

Comment: that doesn't work that why I posted this question

Comment: @hariszaman if you use autolayout then the problem will be solved easily otherwise you have to set the frame explicitly in order to show the view at the right place.

Comment: have you tried using purely autolayout?
So you add the image, and then tag the image to the bottom of the scrollview, and make the imageview inside the scroll view..
Is there a specific reason why you didn't use autolayout? if you give more information I'll be able to post a more helpful answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `autoresizing` then you need to set `left`, `right`, `bottom` and `flexibleWidth` masks to both `UIImageView` and `UIScrollView`. Take a look at the images attached here.

If your `UIScrollView` covers the whole screen then set all the resizing masks for `it` but for `UIImageView` set only the ones stated above.

Hope it helps.

[image]
[image]

Output in simulator:

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]

Answer (score 5):

`Autoresizingmask` does not work when you use auto layout. AutoLayout will turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of views decoded from storyboard file. But you can still set it to `YES` in code if you want to. But I don't recommend you to do that. Stick to AutoLayout if you want to keep it simple and elegant. What you should do is to use AutoLayout to layout the image view.

What you want to do here can't be done  only in IB. AutoLayout layout views based on their edges. In your case, the relation between image view and scroll view is different in portrait and landscape orientation. In portrait orientation, the image view's bottom edge is aligned with scroll view's bottom edge. But in landscape orientation, the image view's top edge is aligned with scroll view's bottom edge. There is no way to use only one set of constraints to achieve your goal. You can add a constraint to image view in IB which aligns image view's bottom edge with scroll view's bottom edge like the first picture in your question. Then `IBOutlet` that constraint to your view controller. When device's orientation changed, you can just change the constant of the constraint. It is something like this:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) UIImageView *imageView; // the image view
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSLayoutConstraint *imageBottomToScrollView; // the constraint you added in IB to the image view

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
        self.imageBottomToScrollView.constant = -CGRectGetHeight(self.imageView.frame);
    } else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
        self.imageBottomToScrollView.constant = 0;
    }
}


@end
```

It's very easy~

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have already done that using coding but as specified I am looking for interface builder only solution

Comment: @hariszaman that just can't be done only in IB. Some layout task must be done in code.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add this method in your view controller.

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    CGSize contentSize = self.scrollView.contentSize;
    CGRect frame = self.imageView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.size.width = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    frame.size.height = Expected_Height;
    frame.origin.y = contentSize.height - frame.size.height;
    self.imageView.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: Why? The questioner is using `autoresizingmask` so this is the only way to do that.

Comment: I just quoted the note.

Comment: Ah, sorry I don't notice that.

Answer (score 2):

Autoresizingmask won't work with auto layout, in you IB, Add a Top space constraint on the image it will show your image at then end of scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve the "problem" using IB only, because you have to change scrollview's content size regarding  the orientation. If you want your image view to be overlapped by tabbar, you have to manually set the content size for your scrollview equal to `screen_height + abs(tabbar_height - imageview_height)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pin the uiimageview to the bottom of you scrollview and it will take into account the contentSize. Hope that helps

[image]